# NodeJS stream returns incomplete response

Tags: node.js, streaming, nestjs, httpresponse, request-promise

I am using [lento](https://github.com/vweevers/lento) (Streaming Node.js client for Presto, the "Distributed SQL Query Engine for Big Data") for querying database. Lento's `createRowStream` takes sql query as a string or Buffer and returns a readable stream that yields rows.

Before returning the resulted row stream, I need to do some pre-processing on the result (`stream.pipe()` does that for me) and convert it to CSV format ([csvStringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stringify) does that for me)

Once the stream ends, I resolve the promise with `resolve()` callback and also log the number of rows streamed. But, compared to the number of rows streamed, the actual rows returned are less. For example, if the log says count is 10000 (variable `rowsCnt`) the number of rows returned would be close to 6000.

What could be the cause for the inconsistency in number of rows returned?

Please check below imports and code snippet:

```
import csvStringify from 'csv-stringify';
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
import lento from 'lento';
import streamTransform from 'stream-transform';
```

```
async getCSVRows(res: Response, sqlQueries: sqlDto[]): Promise<void> {
    const result = [];
    const lentoClient = ... code to create instance of lento client
    for (let index = 0; index < sqlQueries.length; index++) {
        const csvStream = csvStringify({header: index == 0 ? true : false});
        queryResult = executeQuery(res, sqlQueries[index], lentoClient, csvStream)
        result.push(queryResult)
    }
    await Promise.all(result);
    res.end()
}

async executeQuery(
    res: Response, 
    sqlQuery: sqlDto, 
    lentoClient: any, 
    csvStream: csvStringify.Stringifier
): Promise<Response> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        const rowsStream = lentoClient.createRowStream(sqlQuery.query); 
        let rowsCnt = 0;
        rowsStream.on('data', function() {})
        .pipe(
            streamTransform((row: any) => {
                 // process row
                 rowsCnt++;
                 return row;
            }),
        )
        .pipe(csvStream)
        .pipe(res, {end: false});
        rowsStream.on('error', (err: Error) => {
            // log error
            throw err;
        });
        rowsStream.on('end', () => {
             resolve(res);
             console.log('Rows count: ' + rowsCnt);
        });
    });
}
```

Note: Framework used is NestJS

Answer (score 1):

I think you are ending the responses too early, when there is still processing going on in the pipeline. In your code, when rowsStream emits the 'end' event, doesn't mean its the end of processing. It means that the last chunk of query results are in the pipeline, but still processing and are being sent to the client. You need to end the response after all of the processing is done and the pipeline is empty. It's tricky, because you are piping multiple queries in the same response, so you use the {end: false} option. Because of this, "res" won't emit the end event so you have to detect the end of processing some other way.

Here is my take:
mergeStream(...csvStreams) will emit 'end' when all of the queries are finished processing, with that ending the response.

The header row of the CSV is still not guaranteed to be in the first chunk written to the response though.

```
import csvStringify from 'csv-stringify';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import lento from 'lento';
import streamTransform from 'stream-transform';
import mergeStream from 'merge-stream';



createCSVRowStream(
  sqlQuery: sqlDto,
  lentoClient: any,
  csvStream: csvStringify.Stringifier,
) {
  return lentoClient
    .createRowStream(sqlQuery.query)
    .pipe(
      streamTransform((row: any) => {
        // process row

        return row;
      }),
    )
    .pipe(csvStream);
}

  getCSVRows(res: Response, sqlQueries: sqlDto[]) {
    //const lentoClient = ... code to create instance of lento client

    const csvStreams = sqlQueries.map((sqlQuery, index) =>
      createCSVRowStream(
        sqlQuery,
        lentoClient,
        csvStringify({ header: index == 0 ? true : false }),
      ),
    );
    res.status(200);
    mergeStream(...csvStreams).pipe(res);
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Dani, Thank you for your suggestion , but, like I have mentioned in my question, the 'end' event does get invoked because, I am able to see `Rows count` log, which is a part of 'end' event.

Comment: Yes, it does on rowsStream. The 'end' event listener code in your post will run after rowsStream loaded all of the query result data chunks in memory. csvStream might be still producing csv rows and data is being sent to and waiting in line to be sent to the client. Promise.all will return when csvStream is still emitting 'data' csv rows and wants to write it to the response, but it's not able to do so because the response is already closed.